# I would like to call an object in an object to other class in c++

Tags: c++, class, object

```
class Player {
public:
    // something
    double getVelPlayer();

private:
    // something
    sf::Sprite mPlayer;
};

class Game {
public:
    // something
private:
    void processEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    // something
};
void Game::update() {
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.f, 0.f);
    if(mIsMovingUp)
        movement.y -= player.getVelPlayer() * timeElapsed.asMilliseconds();
    if(mIsMovingDown)
        movement.y += player.getVelPlayer() * timeElapsed.asMilliseconds();
    if(mIsMovingLeft)
        movement.x -= player.getVelPlayer() * timeElapsed.asMilliseconds();
    if(mIsMovingRight)
        movement.x += player.getVelPlayer() * timeElapsed.asMilliseconds();
    player.mPlayer.move(movement);
}

void Game::render() {
    mWindow.clear();
    mWindow.draw(player.mPlayer);
    mWindow.display();
}
int main() {
    Player* player = new Player;
    Game* game = new Game;

    delete game;
    delete player;

    return 0;
}
```

i get an error : ‘player’ was not declared in this scope

I need to get the mPlayer object from the player object to Game::update and Game::update.

But I keep get an error if i try to comlile

How can I declare Player.getVelPlayer or draw(player.mPlayer)?

Since mPlayer is an object, I think I have to call an object in an object, but I don't know how.

Comment: That's not the error I get from that code so your problem isn't reproducible. I get `error: ‘sf’ does not name a type`     `sf::Sprite mPlayer;` - Please make a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I am using SFML. I forgot to explain.

Comment: The [tag:sfml] parts don't have to do with the problem though so you should be able to remove those parts to make a [mcve].

Comment: I am curruntly tring to use the sf::Sprite object, which is built in Player class, for the Game class. So maybe you can just make a empty class of Sprite.

Comment: Yes, well, creating the [mcve] is usually something that should be done by the person who asks the question so that people trying to help can just copy the code and try to compile it to reproduce the problem the questioner asks about. In this case I managed to see the problem without being able to reproduce the same error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Game` class doesn't have a member variable called `player` and the `Player` you allocate in `main` isn't accessible from within a `Game` object.

Consider moving the `Player` into the `Game` class - and there's no need to use `new`:

```
class Game {
public:
    // something
private:
    void processEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    // something

    Player player; // a Player will be created when a `Game` is created.
};
```

```
int main() {
    Game game; // no need to new / delete

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Also, is there a way to build an player object in main and call a mPlayer in Game class?

Comment: @OKUU Sure, you can let them have almost any relationship. A game without a player, a player without a game, a game composed of a player and other objects etc. It all depends on what you'd like.

Comment: @OKUU Did you try moving the `Player` into `Game` - or do you want `Game` instances to be able to exist without a `Player`?

Comment: Yes. I already moved the player into game, and found that it worked without an error. However, as you said, I want Game instances to be able to exist without a Player.

Comment: what detail should I add?

Comment: @OKUU Describe the relationship you'd like to have between the two objects and how you are planning to use them. If you don't explain why you'd like to be able to create a `Game` object that doesn't contain a `Player` I think people will suggest that you move the `Player` instance into `Game`. Is it a multiplayer or single player game? That may also be useful info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333870/additional-detail-for-ted-lyngmo

Comment: I made another question

Comment: @OKUU Yeah, I noticed my name in the list of questions :-) I made a comment to it.

Comment: sorry for being absent for a long time. My linux file was all gone and I failed to manage the files. also sorry for the inaproppriate question. I should have read the rules. Since my files are all gone, I think I have to ask this question after a little time.

Comment: @OKUU Oh, that's unfortunate! :-( I hope you manage to get back on track with your code and don't worry about the previous question. It a simple mistake anyone could have done when starting out here.